# Oracle table result set in xml format

Tags: xml, oracle, select, stored-procedures

Environment : Oracle Express 11g

I have developed an Oracle stored procedure to return multiple records from table in xml format. Unfortunately it is working for single records. For multiple records it is returning error

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Please suggest how to fix error.

### Stored procedure

```
create or replace function view_to_xml return clob as
  xml xmltype;
 data clob;
begin
select XMLELEMENT("PERSONS",
   (
     select XMLELEMENT("PERSON",
                 XMLELEMENT("SNO",SNO),
                 XMLELEMENT("NAME",name),
                 XMLELEMENT("AGE",AGE) 
   ) as "result" from person 
   )
   ) into xml from dual;

 SELECT XMLSerialize(DOCUMENT xml AS CLOB) into data FROM DUAL;

return data;
end ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping each element from query to persons

```
select XMLELEMENT("PERSONS",
```

you should aggreagete them to one element using [XMLAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm) :

```
select XMLELEMENT("PERSONS", XMLAGG(person_))
into xml 
from
(
  select XMLELEMENT("PERSON",
                 XMLELEMENT("SNO",SNO),
                 XMLELEMENT("NAME",name),
                 XMLELEMENT("AGE",AGE)) as person_
   from person 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stawros, Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried but could not resolve problem using XMLAGG. I was able to solved problem differently. Here is the solution

```
create or replace function view_to_xml return clob as
  xml xmltype;
  ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
  resultset sys_refcursor;

begin

 open resultset for
 select * from PERSONS;
 ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(resultset);
 dbms_xmlgen.setrowsettag(ctx, 'PERSONS');
 dbms_xmlgen.setrowtag(ctx, 'PERSON');

 xml:= dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(ctx);
 dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(ctx);
 close resultset;

 return xml.getStringVal();
end
```